# Technical name for first time user login tutorial

Tags: npm

I'm trying to search for a npm module, gem or something that helps me in creating a first time login tutorial for a new user into my app...

As I don't know the technical name for this, is very difficult to google it since all of the results end up in tutorial or documentation of a particular library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tooltip tour**

If I understand you correct you are looking for something like this:
http://introjs.com/ on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js

```
npm install intro.js --save
```

And to google for comparisons
https://www.google.com/#q=tooltip+tour++javascript

Comment: Thanks @54N1, This is exactly what I need, but I need to know how to google it for getting comparisons, and for that I need a more precise word.

Comment: tooltip tour is what to look for I think!

Comment: Thanks! And I've found this nice react component for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tour-guide

Answer (score 0):

Other names are:

1. Coach Mark
2. Instructional Overlay